# Accessing class object elements from a private array class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object, stack-overflow

I have a class BankAccount and one of its private members is BankAccount* customers [10]. I want to place objects of type BankAccount(string s, int a, double c, double r, double s) inside of the array and then access each individual piece of data such as string s with getString() or int a with getAccountNum().  Been trying a lot of stuff but I get a blank black box. How can I just put objects in a private class array?

```
#include "BankAccount.h"

BankAccount::BankAccount() : customers()
{

}

void BankAccount::work()
{
string n = "name";
string* nn = &n;
BankAccount* b = new BankAccount(nn);



customers[0] = b;
go();
}

BankAccount::BankAccount(string* n)
{

name = n;
}
string BankAccount::getName()
{
return *name;
}

void BankAccount::go()
{

string st = customers[0]->getName();
cout << st << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code has a lot more problems than that and I think I'm scared to see the rest. :)

Comment: `BankAccount* b = new BankAccount(); b = new BankAccount(n); BankAccount a[1]; a[0] = *b;` Oh, my.

Comment: You really need to read the chapter about classes in your C++ book, again. You have not got it yet.

Comment: Im getting a writing violation error now. How would I implement this correctly? I've working on this for hours. I just want to store class objects in the array.

Comment: @WilliamWymerus - There is a lot wrong with your code.  One symptom of this is the "writing violation".

Comment: As I said, you need to read your book again. There is far too much wrong here to cover in a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Lightness, if you got something rude like that to say, why don't you back it up with some code. I came on here to learn. Not be ridiculed. So far you have just exhibited characteristics of low self esteem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. Create your member variable array of bank account.
Second. If you dont know how to use pointers, don't use it. You may still put 'BankAccount' in array even if it is not pointer-type you'll still get the same results.

```
BankAccount::BankAccount() : customers()
{

}

void BankAccount::work() 
{
string n = "name";

BankAccount* b = new BankAccount(); //do thus
b = new BankAccount(n);    //dont do this('b' above will create memory leak
BankAccount a[1];    //no need to do this
a[0] = *b;  // and this
customers[0] = a;  // assign 'b' instead of 'a'
```

// customers is your member variable array of BankAccount? Just add method for setting of 'name' or use this 'customers[0].name = n;' you'll still be able to set its member variable 'name'
    }

```
BankAccount::BankAccount(string n)
{
    BankAccount nn;    //don't do this
nn.name = n;    // also this
// if you want to set the value of your member variable 'name', just equate it 'name = n;'  you dont need to create new instance of 'BankAccount'.
}
string BankAccount::getName()
{
    return name;  //this is your only correct item
}

void BankAccount::go()
{
BankAccount b ;    // dobt do this
string st = b.customers[0]->getName();  // almost correct. If you want to get name of 'customer[0]' just use this 'string st = customers[0]->getName();'  or you can easily do print out 'cout << customers[0]->name << endl;'
cout << st << endl;
}
```

I think what your getting wrong here is the use of instance of 'BankAccount' and pointers.
If you want to access member variables, you dont need new instance of it(output will be different if you get value from new instance).

Try reading c++ basics for more detailed info.

i'm using my phone now, so pardon me if i can't explain better. I hope it helps.
and i hope you get you code to work right.
It still needs a lot of work done right.

Comment: This really was not helpful since the array has to be a pointer. There is no other way to declare it as a private member of a class without the object being a pointer. I need to know how to make the array object be filled with elements of its class object.

Comment: Hahaha! If you need to use pointers, try learning how to use them. Anyways. Just change data type of member variable to pointer and use it as pointer. Change access of member variables to '->' instead of '.'

Comment: I got it to work. So thanks for POINTING me in the right direction ;) I'd vote you up but I do not have a rep of 15 or more. Sorry. Wonder why my rep is so low?

Comment: Thanks! :-)  i guess you need to participate to asking and answering questions to raise your rep.

Comment: Just added info. When you use 'new' you have to 'delete', there'll be memory leak otherwise.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for reminding me. I'm redoing the peseduo code now. I was way off before. LoL!